# Engram drop rate increase after House of Wolves patch?

Tags: destiny

Since playing after the massive House of Wolves patch I seem to be getting A LOT of Rare and Legendary Engrams.

Has the drop rate been increased in the latest patch?

I can't find any technical specifications that clarify this but I know a few other players that have experienced the same increase in Engram Drop rate.

---

Comment: In what activities?    Certainly they've said that the drop rate in crucible has been raised, and of course there's the queen's wrath chess.

Comment: I didn't know about the crucible drops, that's good. But I mean just random engram drops from kills seem to be higher chance.

Comment: Flagging to close; whether or not the rate of engram drops has changed is unverifiable and not an answerable "question". (And an obligatory mention of observation bias)

Comment: @sabledreamer this kind of question has been answered.  If you need help on the search funtion please come see mr.

Comment: The drop rate has been increased from my observation as well.

Comment: It may also be that since they introduced so many new legendary items it is just more common now to get a legendary one than a blue one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that in the rewards section of games I am seeing more legendary items, but not necessarily as many legendary *engrams*. That being said, it may be because there were so many new legendaries added to the game that they outnumber the blue items now and as a result show up more often in general. Most of this broad observation is conjecture.

I also play a lot of PvP and have definitely noticed a difference there. This part is *not* conjecture, and as noted directly in the patch notes

> **PvP**
>   - Increased Rare Weapons and Gear drop chance for completing games across all playlists by 100%
>   - Added Legendary Weapon drops into the Crucible reward stream across all playlists

https://www.bungie.net/7_Destiny-Update---05152015/en/News/News?aid=12887